# Vert.x - Preserve row order in bulk insert using JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql-server, vert.x

I am trying to do bulk insert in MSSQL database using vertx java and for some reason the insertion is not being done in the table in the same order I arrange the data in the List. It is very important for my business logic to have this order in the database.In the console it shows the order correctly but when I view it in the database the order is all mixed up.

```
public void insertChildUid(SortedSet<String> goodReadSet, Integer serialID) {
        LOG.debug(" serialID "+serialID);
        List<JsonArray> batch = new ArrayList<JsonArray>();
        
        int childSetSize = goodReadSet.size();
        LOG.debug(" childSetSize "+childSetSize);
        String[] goodReadArray = new String[childSetSize];
        goodReadArray = goodReadSet.toArray(goodReadArray);
        
        for (int i=0; i < childSetSize; i++) {
            String[] puidAndUid = new String[1];            
            puidAndUid = goodReadArray[i].split(":");
            String puid = puidAndUid[0];
            String uid = puidAndUid[1];

            batch.add(new JsonArray().add(uid).add(puid).add(serialID));
        }
        String sql = "INSERT INTO serial"
                        + " (uid, fnc, serialorderid)"
                        + " VALUES(?, ?, ?) ";
        
        LOG.debug("SQL QUERY :"+formatQuery(sql, batch));
        
        dbClient.getConnection(conn->{
            if(conn.failed()){
                LOG.error("Can't get Vertx connection",conn.cause());
            } else{
                LOG.debug(" Vertx connected for BATCH INSERT!!!!!!!!!");
                
                final SQLConnection connection = conn.result();                          
                connection.batchWithParams(sql,batch,(AsyncResult<List<Integer>> res) -> {
                  if (res.succeeded()) {
                        List<Integer> result = res.result();
                        LOG.debug("result : "+result.size());
                        //LOG.debug("BATCH INSERT COMPLETE!!!!!!!!!");
                        LOG.debug(" BATCH INSERT COMPLETE FOR PUID!!!!!!!!! "+batch.get(0).getString(1));
                      } else {
                        // Failed!
                          LOG.debug("Failed! : "+res.cause());
                      }
                    });
                connection.close();
            }
        });
        
    }
```

**Below is my console output**

*

> 11:41:04.569 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO -  childSetSize 10

> 11:41:04.570 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO - SQL QUERY :INSERT INTO serial (uid, fnc, serialorderid) VALUES([["11980005339800793304","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980013237900080767","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980018018100688258","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980018208300933667","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980018213800239089","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980018531200237597","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980023406000938288","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980027390300806466","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980028239900198090","11980180231000164186",72], ["11980028320100716616","11980180231000164186",72]], {1}, {2})

> $$$$$$$$  11980183084300807471  $$$$$$$$$$$

> 11:41:04.571 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.OrderDAO - arraySize 5

> 11:41:04.572 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.OrderDAO - arraySize+childCounter 1510
> Iterating over set: 5
> CONSTR SerialOrderDAO!!

> 11:41:04.572 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO -  serialID 72

> 11:41:04.572 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO -  childSetSize 5

> 11:41:04.572 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO - SQL QUERY :INSERT INTO serial (uid, fnc, serialorderid) VALUES([["11980053655800913678","11980183084300807471",72], ["11980080273700614629","11980183084300807471",72], ["11980082028600001574","11980183084300807471",72], ["11980082222200939079","11980183084300807471",72], ["11980088238100084516","11980183084300807471",72]], {1}, {2})

> 11:41:04.572 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.OrderDAO - serials are created and saved in database

> 11:41:04.573 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO -  Vertx connected for BATCH INSERT!!!!!!!!!

> 11:41:04.576 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO -  Vertx connected for BATCH INSERT!!!!!!!!!

> 11:41:04.585 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO - result : 5

> 11:41:04.585 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO -  BATCH INSERT COMPLETE FOR PUID!!!!!!!!! 11980183084300807471

> 11:41:04.585 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO - result : 10

> 11:41:04.585 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG tntmanual.server.dao.SerialOrderDAO -  BATCH INSERT COMPLETE FOR PUID!!!!!!!!! 11980180231000164186*

[![table output in database][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ49U.gif

Comment: Define exactly what you mean with "view it in the database the order is all mixed up". Rows in a table have no particular order by definition. If you want an ordered set, the query that generates it must include an order by clause. If insertion order is important, then your schema must include columns needed for that purpose and something (your code probably) must populate it correctly.

Comment: I mean see my console output first it shows the insert for fnc= 11980180231000164186, which is of size 10 and then it inserts fnc= 11980183084300807471 which is of size 5, but in the database it has not inserted in the same order i.e. first all the 10 fnc with 11980180231000164186 then the 5 fnc with 11980183084300807471

Comment: my table DDL is follows
`CREATE TABLE serial (
   id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
   uid nvarchar(20),
   fnc nvarchar(56),
   serialorderid bigint NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PK__serial__3213E83F843DE058 PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT FK__serial__serialor__3A81B327 FOREIGN KEY (serialorderid) REFERENCES tntmanual.dbo.serialorder(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) `